# Can anyone outside use my api to make requests?

Tags: node.js, json, api, rest, express

I am currently learning full stack dev, and have made a simple application with React on the front end, and set up a very simple REST api on my express web server that handles certain routes.

For example `api/users` returns a list of users from my database and returns responses as JSON data. `api/blogs` can return a list of blogs in JSON with a get request, or post a blog with a post request.

I have learned and been able to implement very basic user tokenization with JWT, and so only logged in users with a valid token can make a post of a blog for example. This is done by adding their token with `bearer` as a Authentication header in the request, which the server verifies.  This makes sense to me, however I am very confused on how the backend works or if I am doing something critically wrong.

If I go to my main page for my application, and type `api/blogs` it opens up a page displaying JSON data. Anyone can basically view this from my application by going to `api/endpoint`
I am also assuming anyone from outside can use something like Postman to send a post request to my database assuming they have the token which they got since my token is saved in storage.

This is incredibly weird to me Is this just how these things work? Or am I failing to understand something crucial?

if I wanted to progress forward and learn more about this, where or what do I do?

Comment: Yes, that's right, they can. I'm thinking: if it's not sensitive data, it's not worth worrying about. If it is sensitive data, make sure your API is set up to only provide access to those with authorization. Remember that essentially everything done on the client can easily be seen by someone who opens the developer tools.

Comment: Do a majority of web apps use this approach? I never knew you can view JSON data from any website assuming they have a route that returns that JSON data?

Comment: I think so, yes. Yes, it's very easy to see network payloads if someone is curious and knows their way around, and often the requests needed to make those payloads can then be emulated.

Answer (score 0):

You have described how users authenticate to your application (with a bearer token), but what steps does your application take before issuing such a token?

- Does your application keep a database of users and their passwords?

  - If yes, can anyone sign up by inventing a user name and password?
  - Do you verify an email address before admitting a new user?
- Or does your application rely on an external OpenID Connect service (for example, login with your Google or Facebook account)?

  - If yes, can anyone with a Google or Facebook account sign up for your application?
- Or must an application admin (that is, you) put the user on an "allow-list"?

To summarize: Unless you take special precautions, anyone from outside can sign up to your application and subsequently use it.

Comment: Yes my application hashes users passwords and stores them in the db. Then when a user signs up (my app sends a post request to a /users endpoints) it checks if username already exists and returns error if it does, from there it authenticates them and when they sign in the server sends a token associated with their name and user.id in mongo. But everything else you said is stuff I had entirely overlooked! Thanks!